# Service Command - Why service --status-all and service SERVICENAME status returning different results?

Tags: networking, ssh, users, services

I am connecting to my local VMs via ssh private key.

My understanding is the `service SERVICENAME status` returns the detailed status of the service and the output mentions that the service is 'Active' if the service is running. The other option to know the status of the service is `--status-all` followed by a grep filter. This returns `[ + ]` the service is running and `[ - ]` if the service is not running.

In my case I have fired both commands, one by one. First I tried with the `service --status-all | tomcat8` and then with `service tomcat8 status`. These both commands displays different results. I can confirm that the process tomcat8 is actually running on the server. But the result of the `--status-all` is confusing me. It should have been `[ + ]`.

```
ubuntu@vm-local-pd00:~$ service --status-all | grep tomcat8
 [ - ]  tomcat8
ubuntu@vm-local-pd00:~$ service tomcat8 status
● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-12-13 14:26:25 IST; 11h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 671 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat8.service
           └─728 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.uti

Dec 13 14:26:03 vm-local-pd00 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
Dec 13 14:26:12 vm-local-pd00 tomcat8[671]:  * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat8
Dec 13 14:26:25 vm-local-pd00 tomcat8[671]:    ...done.
Dec 13 14:26:25 vm-local-pd00 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Tomcat..
Dec 13 22:19:06 vm-local-pd00 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Tomcat..
```

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something here?

Note: The remote Ubuntu version is 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64)

Comment: Did you read it's man page?

Comment: that's what i am doing at the moment, but didn't find any help from the man. I expect the `--status-all` should have returned `[ + ]`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? If it's 16.04+ you should probably be using the equivalent `systemctl` commands (e.g. `systemctl list-unit-files | grep ssh`). AFAIK the `service ... ` commands are only included for backward compatibility with `upstart`-based systems.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64). Edited the question.

Comment: What does `/etc/init.d/tomcat8 status` output?

Comment: @muru it return exactly same result as `service tomcat8 status`. 
`tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-12-14 12:49:23 IST; 1min 48s ago`

Comment: I dont understand this either:  it is the same for `apache-htcacheclean`. Different results. But according to source code http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/sysvinit/trusty-updates/view/head:/debian/service/service#L68, it should actually do the same thing! (because there is no `/etc/init/apache-htcacheclean`